Calling a function that execute Python in C++ from Python gives a free() invalid pointer error
I write a function that executes a Python string in C++ using the Python C API.
The function works perfectly. When I run it, it executes the Python string.
The problem occurs when I make a .so file and then call the same function from the Python side using C++.
It gives a weird error. free() invalid pointer on Py_Initialize(); this line.
When I comment down the line, then a segmentation fault occurs.

My runner.cpp code is:
#include <vector>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

typedef void (*Py_Initialize_t)();
typedef int (*PyRun_SimpleString_t)(const char *);
typedef void (*Py_Finalize_t)();


std::string execute_command(const char* command) {
    FILE* pipe = popen(command, "r");
    if (!pipe) {
        return "Error executing command";
    }

    std::ostringstream output;
    char buffer[128];
    while (!feof(pipe)) {
        if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != nullptr) {
            output << buffer;
        }
    }

    // Close the pipe and return the output
    pclose(pipe);
    return output.str();
}

std::vector<std::string> split_string(const std::string& input, char delimiter) {
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::istringstream iss(input);
    std::string token;
    while (std::getline(iss, token, delimiter)) {
        tokens.push_back(token);
    }
    return tokens;
}

void execute_Prog730(std::string program) {
    std::cout << "Running Engine" << std::endl;
    std::string python_version_output = execute_command("python3 -c \"import sys; print(sys.version)\"");
    size_t start_pos = python_version_output.find_first_of("0123456789");
    size_t end_pos = python_version_output.find_first_not_of("0123456789.", start_pos);
    std::string python_version = python_version_output.substr(start_pos, end_pos - start_pos);
    std::vector<std::string> parts = split_string(python_version, '.');

    std::ostringstream lib_name_stream;
    lib_name_stream << "libpython" << parts[0] << '.' << parts[1] << ".so";
    std::string lib_name = lib_name_stream.str();
    std::cout << lib_name << std::endl;
    void* handle = dlopen(lib_name.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);
    if(!handle && lib_name.back() == 'o') {
        std::string  lib_name_so1 = lib_name + ".1";
        handle = dlopen(lib_name_so1.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);
    }

    if (!handle) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load Python library" << std::endl;
        //return 1;
    }

    auto Py_Initialize = (Py_Initialize_t)dlsym(handle, "Py_Initialize");
    auto PyRun_SimpleString = (PyRun_SimpleString_t)dlsym(handle, "PyRun_SimpleString");
    auto Py_Finalize = (Py_Finalize_t)dlsym(handle, "Py_Finalize");

    if (!Py_Initialize || !PyRun_SimpleString || !Py_Finalize) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to resolve Python functions" << std::endl;
        dlclose(handle);
    }
    std::cout << "Debug" << std::endl;
    Py_Initialize();
    std::cout << "Debug" << std::endl;
    PyRun_SimpleString(program.c_str());
    Py_Finalize();
    dlclose(handle);
}

My runner.h file is:
#include <iostream>
#include "runner.cpp"

void execute_Prog730(std::string program);

My main.cpp file is:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string.h>

#include <runner.h>

extern "C" void run(const char* program) {
    std::string pr(program);
    std::cout << pr << std::endl;
    execute_Prog730(pr);
}

The command I use to compile:
g++ -o main.so --shared -fPIC main.cpp -I/home/lakshit/Desktop/temp/include

Finally my main.py file is:
import ctypes

module = ctypes.CDLL('/home/lakshit/Desktop/temp/main.so')

func = module.run
func.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]

func(b"print('hello')")

Note:
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish). Some versions require to add -ldl command to compile the .so file successfully.

First of all, please don't add the C language for a C++ question. There are few cases where it might be done, but this isn't one of them. Please read the C or C++ tag wikis for when you can use both tags.

As for your problem of integrating C++ and Python, there are a few libraries that will let you do that in a very nice C++-ish way. And that includes creating Python modules which can be imported directly, instead of relying on ctype. I really recommend you look up a couple of them to help you.

By the way, please read Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?

there are some libraries like pybind . we import the module directly but how it going to sove this problem , and migrating whole code , will be difficult

Given that you're running this from Python, Python is already initialized so it makes no sense to call Py_Initialize yourself. And especially not to call Py_Finalize when you're done

I tried commenting Py_Initialize  and Py_Finalize it gives segementation fault core dumped

Read about how to extend and embed Python in the documentation.

In the situation you presented, your current process already has a libpython loaded. Why are you doing all of that work again? You should link main.so against the same Python library version doing the loading, and then the linker will look up the Py_* functions for you. The entirety of execute_Prog730 can be reduced to just the PyRun_SimpleString call then.

you probably want to use RTLD_NOLOAD to ensure it will lookup PyRun_SimpleString from the already-loaded symbol table

using RTLD_NOLOAD results in failed to load python library and hence segmentation fault , also as Botje suggest only using PyRun_SimpleString causes same error

if it is failing with RTLD_NOLOAD then you have the wrong path, which shows that the error you get from using Py_Initialize is because it is trying to load 2 different python interpreter versions at the same time ... a lot of symbol clash is happening there, i would first try to make sure the path is correct using ldd

path is correct i tried with absolute path also , and my system have only python3.10

try adding RTLD_GLOBAL ie: RTLD_NOLOAD | RTLD_GLOBAL, also remove Py_Initialize.

    void* handle = dlopen(t.c_str(), RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NOLOAD);
``` still handle is null

i tried that on my system ... it works ... up to the points where it  crashes because you need to acquire the GIL before you call into python ...

so we need to aquire gil at cpp side in python in order to run the pyrun_simplestring ??

Thanks Ahmed acquiring gil resolve my issue

To summarize the comment discussion:

since Python is already loaded, you shouldn't call Py_Initialize and Py_Finalize
since the Python DLL file is already loaded, you need to load it with RTLD_NOLOAD
you need to acquire the GIL before you call Python from the C++ side, this is because ctypes.CDLL drops the GIL when calling C code.

If you are calling a C function that you know will use the Python C API you should instead use ctypes.PyDLL which doesn't drop the GIL, and you won't need to re-acquire it from the C++ side.
The following code solves the issue on my system.
#include <vector>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

namespace {

    enum PyGILState_STATE
    {
        locked, unlocked
    };

    using PyRun_SimpleString_t = int (*)(const char *);
    using PyGILState_Ensure_t = PyGILState_STATE (*)(void);
    using PyGILState_Release_t = void (*)(PyGILState_STATE);
}

std::string execute_command(const char* command) {
    FILE* pipe = popen(command, "r");
    if (!pipe) {
        return "Error executing command";
    }

    std::ostringstream output;
    char buffer[128];
    while (!feof(pipe)) {
        if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != nullptr) {
            output << buffer;
        }
    }

    // Close the pipe and return the output
    pclose(pipe);
    return output.str();
}

std::vector<std::string> split_string(const std::string& input, char delimiter) {
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::istringstream iss(input);
    std::string token;
    while (std::getline(iss, token, delimiter)) {
        tokens.push_back(token);
    }
    return tokens;
}

void execute_Prog730(std::string program) {
    std::cout << "Running Engine" << std::endl;
    std::string python_version_output = execute_command("python3 -c \"import sys; print(sys.version)\"");
    size_t start_pos = python_version_output.find_first_of("0123456789");
    size_t end_pos = python_version_output.find_first_not_of("0123456789.", start_pos);
    std::string python_version = python_version_output.substr(start_pos, end_pos - start_pos);
    std::vector<std::string> parts = split_string(python_version, '.');

    std::ostringstream lib_name_stream;
    lib_name_stream << "libpython" << parts[0] << '.' << parts[1] << ".so";
    std::string lib_name = lib_name_stream.str();
    std::cout << lib_name << std::endl;
    void* handle = dlopen(lib_name.c_str(), RTLD_NOLOAD); // Use the already-loaded Python interpreter
    if(!handle && lib_name.back() == 'o') {
        std::string  lib_name_so1 = lib_name + ".1";
        handle = dlopen(lib_name_so1.c_str(), RTLD_NOLOAD);
    }

    if (!handle) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load Python library" << std::endl;
        //return 1;
    }

    auto PyRun_SimpleString = (PyRun_SimpleString_t)dlsym(handle, "PyRun_SimpleString");
    auto PyGILState_Ensure = (PyGILState_Ensure_t)dlsym(handle, "PyGILState_Ensure");
    auto PyGILState_Release = (PyGILState_Release_t)dlsym(handle, "PyGILState_Release");

    if (!PyRun_SimpleString || !PyGILState_Ensure || !PyGILState_Release) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to resolve Python functions" << std::endl;
        if (handle)
        {
            dlclose(handle);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Debug" << std::endl;
    auto state = PyGILState_Ensure(); // Acquire GIL
    PyRun_SimpleString(program.c_str());
    PyGILState_Release(state); // Release GIL
    if (handle)
    { dlclose(handle); }
}

print('hello')
Running Engine
libpython3.10.so
Failed to load Python library
Debug
hello

The Failed to load Python library happens because the main Python executable doesn't load libpython3, and instead statically links it, so those functions are loaded from the executable, not the shared library. If another version of Python dynamically links libpython3 then it will succeed.

You can probably avoid PyPyGILState_Ensure (note typo here in your code) with ctypes.PyDLL which doesn't release the GIL for the call. (Or OP could avoid the whole thing with eval...)

If using ctypes to call a C or C++ function that uses the Python C API, use ctypes.PyDLL to load the dynamic library and it will take care of acquiring the GIL, instead of ctypes.CDLL, which releases it.
